# How to fix adminer.php json error with mysql 5.7 as it is working correctly with other data types?

Tags: php, adminer

I have upgraded mysql from 5.2 to 5.7 and also upgraded adminer.php version as suggested on mysql site and adminer docs.Adminer is working fine with all other data types but not working with json data.NO write query is not working with adminer in browser.I tried many things as per suggested from docs but its not going good?
Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to find any permanent solution but by using raw queries in adminer.php any operation can be performed easily.I hope it will help for new ones.
Still looking for a better solution.